# Bash scripting : How do I rename files to remove numeric characters at the beginning?

Tags: linux, command-line, pattern-matching, gnu

mv command doesnt accept pattern matching like grep !
Whats the good way to handle this and similar kind of operations ?

Answer (score 2):

There's the `rename` tool, but if that's not what you want, you can do:

```
for file in *; do
    new_file="${file##[0-9]}" # Strip all leading numbers
    mv "$file" "$newfile"
done
```